# Pretrained model for RNN Encoder-Decoder?

Tags: nlp, reinforcement-learning, sequence-to-sequence, text-generation

Our team are implementing a paper called [Cold-Start-Reinforcement-Learning-with-Softmax-Policy-Gradient](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09346).

Although the paper didn't mention. We want to use a pre-trained model, which is a RNN Encoder-Decoder based.

Are there any recommend for NLP Summarization with it?

Here are our [code](https://github.com/jacksonchen1998/Cold-Start-Reinforcement-Learning-with-Softmax-Policy-Gradient).

Thanks all.

Comment: Just curious, why not using a model with Transformers?

Comment: @Memristor We want to reproduce the paper, and the paper didn't use Transformers.